# Month names inflection in Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, localization

I would like to use different case of month name in Polish. For example now it works like this:

```
>> I18n.l Time.now, :format => "%e %B"
=> "14 styczeń"
```

but I would like to specify another format of month:

```
>> I18n.l Time.now, :format => "%e %Q"
=> "14 stycznia"
```

Translated month names are in my pl.yml file in `pl.date.month_names`. And I don't want to change it. I can add `pl.date.another_month_names` in the other case, but I don't know how to make `I18n.l` method to use it.

So how can I achive that? Other solutions (helpers, custom methods etc.) are also welcome.

Comment: You hit a tough subject that's been haunting localisers for a long time - how to deal with languages more sophisticated than English. What you suggested below as an answer to your own question is more of a workaround than a solution but it seems to be the best approach until localisations get a more sophisticated inflection support, at least something similar to what pluralisation already has.

Answer (score 7):

i had a similar problem with strange month names in german translation.
I had to configure the month names in my locale.yml, now it works as expected:

```
de:
  defaults: &defaults
    month_names:
      [~, Januar, Februar, März, April, Mai, Juni, Juli, August, September, Oktober, November, Dezember]
    formats:
       default: "%d. %B %Y"
       short: "%d.%m.%Y"
  date:
    <<: *defaults
  time:
    <<: *defaults
```

Comment: What's the first value in the month_names array?

Comment: In the code, there's comment: "# Don't forget the nil at the beginning; there's no such thing as a 0th month". That's why.

Answer (score 6):

Since nobody answered my question, I found one solution.

I just created another translation, for example `alt_pl.yml` and I added my custom month names, then:

```
>> I18n.l Time.now, :format => "%e %Q", :locale => :alt_pl
=> "15 stycznia"
```